# Proper way to deliver multiple files to user over internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, download, ext.net

My web client is based on EXT.net grid.
My server is build on ASP.NET web api.
My users using internet explorer (chrome,Firefox) to access my app.
I want to try deliver user multiple files (pdf's) in one iteration (click).
Can I configure my method inside web api controller to deliver multiple files ?
Can I do multiple calls from client in one time so chrome or firefox recive multiple files ?

Whic one is better.

Here is how I do one file download

Client side:

```
<ext:Button ID="test"  Icon="Door" Text="daj mi narudzbu"   runat="server">
   <DirectEvents>
        <Click  
             IsUpload="true"
             FormID="fileform"
             AutoDataBind="true"
             CleanRequest="true" 
             Method="POST"
             Url="http://localhost:44861/desktopmodules/TkmWebApi/api/reportNarudzba/report"
            >
       </Click>
   </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

Server side:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage report()
        {
           HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "narudzba.pdf" };
                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    return response;
        }
```

Comment: If you can use Firefox, downthemall addon may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server cannot simply deliver multiple files. If the files was images you could have embed them to the page. With .pdf you need to need either provide users with multiple links to download the files or use JavaScript to open multiple windows. Something as:

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('pdfurl1');");
Response.Write("window.open('pdfurl2');");
...
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Where pdfurl1, pdfurl2 are addresses of your server page with parameters to deliver file1, file2, ... . 
User will have to confirm download of each file and there will be problem when a popup blocker is active.

If you are using session be aware that only one process can access session so user cannot download files simultaneously, but if the file are small a user probably doesn't notice it.

Other way is to create one file (Zip, tar, ...) and let user to unpack it. Or some kind of browser extension for all browsers.